# Alternatives to xsounds.org for haskell-core on arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, haskell

Every time I attempt to update my arch system using `sudo pacman -Syu` it fails because it failed to retrieve some files. The culprit is my ISP. It doesn't give me a reliable connection to the mirror of the `haskell-core` repository: `xsounds.org`. Not only is it terribly slow but also it fails to download large packages like `haskell-pandoc` mid-way:

```
error: failed retrieving file 'haskell-pandoc-1.13.1-5-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from xsounds.org : Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transferred the last 10 seconds
```

The problem only occurs for the `haskell-core` repository. This is a major inconvenience because I have to run `sudo pacman -Syu` multiple times hoping that this time it will download everything without failing. I'm hoping for a short-term solution. Are there any other mirrors for `haskell-core`?

I already tried the http://www.kiwilight.com/ mirror as mentioned on the [ArchHaskell wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ArchHaskell#.5Bhaskell-core.5D). However this mirror doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Comment: As far as I know, there are no other mirrors for [haskell-core] at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `sudo pacman -Syyu`? Double "y" it will force an update of the local database, so new url for download is provided for pacman.

Comment: This is patently false (that's not what doubling the `y` flag does, and has less to do with this question).